# Java nullSocket

Tags: java, sockets

I see something like this when I try to print the socket object

```
nullSocket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=45720,localport=8182]
```

What does this mean? What is a null socket? Do I have a problem of some sort?

Comment: Where's the code that's producing this output? I suspect you are printing a `null` object before your `Socket` object.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are printing a `null` object before your `Socket` object.